# How to pass schema parameter to a procedure without dynamic sql

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, schema, dynamic-sql

I am trying to pass a parametized schema name (or table name would do) into a procedure without using dynamic SQL.

The process works currently using dynamic but I have been tasked with removing as much dynamic sql from our system as possible.  From research I know that DynamicSQL is the common answer, and there has historically been no way to do this, but things change over time so I'm seeing if anyone has found a better solution.

I have tried:

- creating a dynamic user/login/schema and then setting the default schema on the user and including EXECUTE AS code

  - Does not work because the procedures schema takes precedence on select queries - user default schema is not considered
- Creating Synonyms

  - Does not work because the synonyms cannot be made dynamic/session specific

I am currently at a loss to improve on what exists without completely re-designing the database - not a task I'd take on lightly.

Any other options/suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: No, you have to use dynamic SQL if the Schema is dynamic. You **can't** do something like: `SELECT * FROM @SchemaName.MyTable;`, you would have to do something like: `DECLARE @SchemaName varchar(5) = 'dbo', @SQL varchar(MAX); SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @SchemaName + '.MyTable;'; EXEC(@SQL);`. You could also use `sp_executesql`.

Comment: @Larnu That's actually the solution I have in place at the moment that I've been asked to simplify.  The Dynamic road is well documented, I'm hoping for any other technique that I can trial before putting forward as an option.

Comment: If you have a limited number of schemas, you can use "if": `if @schema_name = 'dbo' select * from dbo.tbl1`; `if @schema_name = 'sch1' select * from sch1.tbl1`

Comment: @sepupic Unfortunately not.  The schema names here would unknown in advance - They'd be holding a session id generated by our web front end and passed in. A similar suggestion that I'd been offered would be to replicate the stored procedures into each schema as they are setup - possible but too time consuming.  Almost the same solution as you have here but with a slightly different twist - multiple procedures instead of multiple code paths.

Comment: In your previous question the first sp use dynamic sql to do many things. You can add one more action: transfer your second sp to the right schema. I don't know though if you want that sp to be executed 1 time only from every schema or many times from different schema

Comment: @sepupic The issue with that (something I had already considered) is I'd need a copy of each stored procedure (nearly 100 at last count) for each session (several hundred consecutive users).  As I said above, possible, but very heavy on resources. Would also require an additional layer of stored procedure. One to be called without schema name by our front end, which would then call the copied proc in the sub schema. The aim here is simplification, I'm just not sure if its achievable.

Comment: >>>I'd need a copy of each stored procedure <<< You need not to copy. I suggested you to TRANSFER sp to the correct schema. ALTER SCHEMA..TRANSFER. It copies nothing. It just changes metadata

Comment: Transfer wouldn't work,  I'd have several users accessing the same stored proc at the same time.  Only way around would be to maintain a template copy and then copy that multiple times.  Could possibly Copy/Run/Delete on each call from each user but I'd be wary of the efficiency hit.

Comment: Although, it would be less of a hit I suppose if I copied on first run only, then clears out only on session close.  I'll do some efficiency testing see what happens.

Comment: Why don't you use #temp tables in your procedures? One procedure can be executed by many users, every user executes the same create table #t; select from #t but no one sees the other's tables

Comment: The tables are used store lists of data that need to persist past connection drop.  In this case a list of catalogue references that are setup by some complex business logic.  Since we do not want to perform these checks each time, we store a list of what products are available in a session. I'm actually testing the copied procedures in each schema, and the performance hit seems acceptable at the moment.  Need to get a bit further in and then start stress testing solution.  Works in theory so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to @Sepupic although the final answer wasn't quite his, but it helped me down the road I needed. A couple of +1s on his comments for the credit.

Solution I finally used:

Stored Procedure to copy a stored proc from schema "template" to schema @SessionID

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[usp_CopySproc]
    @SessionID NVARCHAR(255)
    ,   @ProcName NVARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @strSQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @FullProcName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @FullProcName = @SessionID + '.' + @ProcName

    IF OBJECT_ID(@FullProcName) IS NULL
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Creating ' + @FullProcName

            SET @strSQL = OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID('template.' + @ProcName))
            SET @strSQL = STUFF(@strSQL, PATINDEX('%template%', @strSQL), 8, @SessionID)

            EXEC (@strSQL)
        END
    ELSE
        PRINT @FullProcName + ' already exists'

END
```

I setup a schema on session start up ready to contain procedures and session data.  Then copied the procs in using a command like:

```
DECLARE @strSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
,       @SessionID NVARCHAR(255) = 'mySession'

EXEC dbo.usp_CopySproc @SessionID , 'usp_RefreshPriceSummary'
SET @strSQL = @SessionID + '.usp_RefreshPriceSummary'
EXEC @strSQL @SessionID
```

The procedures I copied could then select from the tables within the session schema without qualifying their schema.

Finally on session close/cleanup I navigated through the object table drop anything with that schema id.